# Why does Nautilus use a separate icon rather than the one already docked from the default install?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, launcher, icons, unity

When Nautilus is running it does not group open instances with the pre-existing docked icon. It adds this file cabinet looking icon to the task bar.  I know this isn't default behavior and I'm wondering what could be causing this?

I believe I started noticing this happening after I upgraded (via update manager) from 11.04 to 11.10.  Not 100% sure about that though.  I do have a quicklist## Heading ##

In the picture I've got my mouse on the extraneous icon.

[image]

Comment: So if I delete my custom nautilus-home.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/ (created to add quicklists) and drag Home from the Dash, then I get default icon grouping under the correct icon.  As soon as I copy /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop into ~/.local/share/applications/ and re-login then the icon grouping behavior is screwed up again.  Even without adding quicklists.

Comment: Workaround I came up with was to add my quicklist jargon directly to '/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop'. This is not an idea solution as I imagine I'll have to reinstate the customized nautilus-home.desktop file anytime its replaced in an update or upgrade.

Comment: It's also not ideal on a multi-user system to apply personal changes to all users, of course...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is open your custom .desktop (nautilus-home.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications

Inside you'll likely find a line  -

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

Remove that line & you can again use your custom .desktop, all nautilus windows will be launched & controlled from the single "Home" icon. A log out/in may be good to do

You may also wish to return the .desktop in /usr to orig. state

A 'bug' report on, though i'm not sure the use of copied .desktops is a bug
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/881235